# Como obter a tag <a> dentro de um <DIV, utilizando XPATH?

Tags: php, dom, xpath

Estou tentando obter os dados de um DIV que contém a seguinte estrutura:

```
<div class="item" style="height:273px">
<a href="/arapiraca/anuncios/detalhes/159695-honda-cg-150-2008">
    <img alt="" src="/i.php?w=148&h=119&f=3,0|4,0&src=uploads/anunciosfotos/2014/04/858a6126588bdace8bc0f144f900d097.jpg"></img>
    <img src="/img/icone-novo.png" alt="" style="position: absolute; z-index: 20; width: 60px; height: 60px; right: -5px; top: -10px; border: 0"></img>
    <strong class="nome" style="font-weight:normal">
        HONDA CG 150 2008 TITAN - KS GASOLINA
    </strong>
    <strong class="valor">
        R$ 4.500,00
    </strong>
    <span class="vendedor">
        <span>
            <img alt="" src="/i.php?w=148&h=60&src=uploads/clientes/2659aa7030bac6f245852b948187188a.jpg"></img>
        </span>
    </span>
</a>
<input class="comparacao" type="checkbox" name="comparacao[159695]" value="159695"></input>
```

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$classname = "item";
$nodes = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classname . "']");

foreach ($nodes as $node) {
     echo $node->nodeValue . " <br> ";
}
```

Com o código acima, consigo obter apenas o seguinte resultado:

```
HONDA CG 150 2008 TITAN - KS GASOLINA R$ 4.500,00
```

Eu preciso também pegar as tags **a**.

Comment: vc quer todas as `<img><span><strong>` dentro de `<a>` ?

Comment: Eu quero obter o que está aqui  **<a href="/arapiraca/anuncios/detalhes/159695-honda-cg-150-2008">**

Comment: `$node->attributes`?

Comment: @Beterraba
`Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMNamedNodeMap could not be converted to string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A expressão XPath que você está usando retorna todos os elementos que possuem atributo `class`com valor `item`:

```
//*[@class='item']
```

É uma coleção. Seu código navega pelos itens dessa coleção, um dos quais é o `div`que você está mostrando.

Se você imprime o valor dessa expressão como string (`nodeValue`), ela só retorna o *conteúdo* de texto dos tags que ela contém. Mas você pode usar expressões XPath absolutas mais elaboradas para obter exatamente o que você quer.

Para obter o *elemento* `a` que está dentro desse `div` você só precisa acrescentar mais um passo:

```
//*[@class='item']/a
```

No caso acima, o XPath está retornando um *elemento*. Se você quiser o conteúdo do *atributo* `href` do elemento `a`, então acrescente mais um passo contendo `@href` ou (`attribute::href`):

```
//*[@class='item']/a/@href
```

Fiquei na dúvida se você queria extrair o texto dentro do `<a>`. Se for o caso (extrair o conteúdo em formato texto de `<strong class='nome'>`), pode fazer isto diretamente em XPath usando:

```
//*[@class='item']//*[@class='nome']/text()
```

A função `text()` retorna o resultado da expressão não como um nó do XML, mas diretamente como uma string. Isto vai afetar a forma como você usa os dados (você pode ler a string, mas não vai poder ler os atributos do elemento que a contém, por exemplo - não pode usar mais `attribute` ou `nodeValue`).

Answer (score 1):

Pode acrescentar uma nova query só com `//a/@href`, ou alterar a query para retornar dois conjuntos de nodos, usando o operador '|'

```
//*[@class='item'] | //a/@href
```

Depois tem que ajustar o ciclo `foreach`, eventualmente.

Bom trabalho!