# Como obter o valor de uma tag com uma class/atributo específico com DOM e php?

Tags: php, html, dom

Olá. É que eu desejo obter o valor de uma determinada tag com uma classe/ atributo específico utilizando DOM e php.
Em baixo está o html que irá ser utilizado:

```
           <div class="header nopadding filmesonline">
                <div class="letter"><i class="fa fa-film">Filmes para ver</i> FILMES</div>
                <div class="button hover active" data-type="movies" data-what="featured">LANÇAMENTOS</div>
                <div class="button hover" data-type="movies" data-what="recent">Recentes</div>
                <div class="button hover" data-type="movies" data-what="mostseen">Mais vistos</div>
                <div class="button hover" data-type="movies" data-what="recommended">Recomendados</div>
            </div>
```

**php**

```
<?php
$allAElements=$d->getElementsByTagName('div');
if ($allAElements){ 
    foreach ($allAElements as $elemento){
        $dataLoader= $elemento->getAttribute('data-loader'); 
        $dataWhat=$elemento->getAttribute('data-what');
        $class=$elemento->getAttribute('class');
        if($class==="header nopadding filmesonline"){
        if($class==="button hover active") $lancamento = $class->nodeValue; 
        var_dump($lancamento);
    }
} 
?>
```

E eu quero com DOM e php obter os valores: Filmes para ver,Filmes, LANÇAMENTOS, Mais vistos e Recomendados e guardar cada um numa variável.
O Html é bem maior mas eu gostaria de obter esses valores que estão em classes e em tags específicas.

Agradecia a vossa ajuda isto é para fazer um trabalho para a faculdade.

Comment: Tentastes algo, esta estudando algum código que está encontrando dificuldade.....http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php

Comment: Relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/51643/diminuir-valor-de-campo-span-com-preg-replace // https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/13712/como-obter-a-tag-a-dentro-de-um-div-utilizando-xpath?rq=1

Comment: @MagicHat eu não posso usar nem expressões regulares nem xpath tem mesmo que ser DOM.

Comment: @MagicHat eu consigo obter o html não consigo é com DOM obter os recursos que quero.

Comment: Entendo, mas o que está tentando ? qual erro está obtendo... ?

Comment: Eu não obtenho os valores que quero. Eu até queria mandar código que tenho escrito mas eu me inscrevi hoje aqui e não estou conseguindo mandar o código. Está sempre dizendo que tem carateres a mais

Comment: clica em [editar] e insere o código....Logo ali abaixo das tags php html dom

Comment: $allAElements=$d->getElementsByTagName('div');
     if ($allAElements){
     foreach ($allAElements as $elemento){
    $dataLoader= $elemento->getAttribute('data-loader');
        $dataWhat=$elemento->getAttribute('data-what');
                    $class=$elemento->getAttribute('class');
                      if($class==="header nopadding filmesonline"){
                          if($class==="button hover active") 
                                  $lancamento = $class->nodeValue;
                                  var_dump($lancamento);
                               }}

Comment: Desculpa mandar assim é que não sei porquê isso está me impedindo de enviar por eu ter carateres a mais :( não sei se isso também acontece com você.